# Girsanov Theorem example

Tags: girsanov

My reference is here : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05309.pdf

My question is related to the example 2.6.1 : page 21-22; **2.6 Girsanov Theorem**

It said in equation (2.8) $Z_t = exp(-\frac{1}{2}∫^t_0θ_s^2ds+∫^t_0θ_sdW_s)$.

And there is outcome for the exponential martingale, $Z_t = exp(-\frac{t}{2}(\frac{(r-μ)}{σ})+\frac{(r-μ)}{σ}W_t)$.

But I don't understand the logic behind this derivation. I want to the procedure how $θ_s$ term changed to $Z_t = exp(-\frac{t}{2}(\frac{(r-μ)}{σ})+\frac{(r-μ)}{σ}W_t)$.

Comment: Papanicolaou simply sets $\theta_s=\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}$. This fraction is known as ''market price of risk'' or ''Sharpe ratio''.

Comment: Then Is it right to solve this equation like this? $df = f_tdt+ f_wdW_t+\frac{1}{2}f_{ww}dt$ and if $f = W_t then, ∫^t_0df = 0 + ∫^t_01dW_t + 0$ So.. because $W_t  = ∫^t_01dW_t = f$, in exponential term, the constant term $θ_s$ multiplied $f$. As a outcome, in the exponential term $∫^t_0θ_sdW_t$ goes to $θ_s*f = θ_sW_t$.